# batch script with set /p entering special characters with escape

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I've created a script that creates a user account as well as sets the account password.  I'm using a separate password generator that includes special characters.  The script fails when entering a password with an ampersand:

```
:: BEGIN Add/change users
set /p UserAcct=Enter User:
set /p UserFullName=Enter Users full name: 
SET /p UserPass=Enter users password: 
net user %UserAcct% %UserPass% /add /profilepath:\\%COMPUTERNAME%\users\%UserAcct% /passwordchg:no /fullname:"%UserFullName%"
wmic useraccount where "name='%UserAcct%'" set passwordexpires=false
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" %UserAcct% /add
:: END
```

Users passwd is `0dfp7&a#zrMd`.
The output:

> ```
> 'a#zrMd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

Comment: No intention to be rude, but you're new and likely don't know. Next time try searching your question? Trust me, theres likely terrabytes of questions about escaping "special" characters.

Answer (score 3):

The `&` is an operator that means "end current command and concatenate another one".
The `%UserPass%` is expanded before the operators and commands are parsed, which causes the problem.

You could escape the `&` as `^&`. But that is not convenient, and you might have to escape other special characters in the string.

The simplest solution is to use delayed expansion, which occurs after the line has been parsed for commands and operators.

```
:: BEGIN Add/change users
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p UserAcct=Enter User:
set /p UserFullName=Enter Users full name: 
SET /p UserPass=Enter users password: 
net user !UserAcct! !UserPass! /add /profilepath:\\!COMPUTERNAME!\users\!UserAcct! /passwordchg:no /fullname:"!UserFullName!"
wmic useraccount where "name='!UserAcct!'" set passwordexpires=false
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" !UserAcct! /add
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with **&** , you need to escape it with a **^** , so provide input **0dfp7^&a#zrMd** instead of **0dfp7&a#zrMd** , to get things working.